# Array.toString data handling in Java

Tags: java, tostring, arrays, array-difference

I'm confused the way data has been manipulated here in this case, thought will seek someones advice.

```
arrayDataOne = [ HEllO, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIPCODE ] 

i.e  
[0] = "HELLO"   
[1] = "NAME"   
[2] = "ADDRESS"   
[3] = "ZIPCODE"

String arrayInString = ( Arrays.toString(arrayDataOne));

i.e
[ HEllO, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIPCODE ] 

String[] arraySplit = arrayInString.split("\\|");

i.e
[0] = [[HEllO, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIPCODE ] ]
```

**Question,**
Why does string value displays as array though logically it's not stored as array in arrayInString ?

Why does arraySplit holds data with in [[ ****data**** ]] ? seems like array of array?

**Edited:** ( added more answer details )

To handle string without "**[**" "**]**" : read [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910507/why-does-arrays-tostringvalues-trim-produce-bracketed-text?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Because that's what .toString does. Read the doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

   > Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified
   >   array. The string representation consists of a list of the array's
   >   elements, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are
   >   separated by the characters ", " (a comma followed by a space).
   >   Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(double).
   >   Returns "null" if a is null.
2. Because it does not match anything when you try to split it. The result therefore is a single bucket the string itself

Comment: so if i'm interested in just plain string of HEllO, NAME, ADDRESS, ZIPCODE without [ ], i should do regex replace on it ? or is it a bad practice ?

Comment: If you want it as array, then do not use .toString. What actually are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks i did find the answer, used StringBuilder to create string.